# Laravel doesn't set a session after successful authentication

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5

I send an ajax call to my subdomain and received a valid `Auth::user();` response as result, but no cookie with a session was returned so all other ajax call fail.

I set

```
'domain' => '.example.com'
```

So all sessions should be accessible to the subdomains.

Comment: Are your routes inside the `web` middleware group?

Comment: no, they aren't, should they? I just have a cors middleware and then the normal auth middleware.

Comment: Okay, found the problem. I removed important Middlewars so it couldn't start a session. After adding them everything works fine.